# Hashicorp Vault - External certificate mangement

Tags: x509certificate, hashicorp-vault

We have a scenario that we have to manage external CA certificates including its expiry validation , revoking and distribution among clients.

Is there any idea for managing the external certificates through Hashicorp vault, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possibility may be to create a sub-CA certificate (or intermediate CA), and then manage it with your Hashicorp Vault. The creation of this sub-CA will not be done with Vault. You will import private & public parts by using pki/config/ca API.

Otherwise, directly manage the external CA seems to be impossible.

Interesting discussion about pki and vault: https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/vault-pki-intermediate-cert-import/5497/5